# 415 Unsupported Media Type while invoking RESTful java web service through ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest

I am trying an example that invokes a restful java web service taking a 'name' as input and posts 'hello name' as follows:

```
     @Path("/login")
     public class LoginWS {
     @POST
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public NameBean getHello( NameBean nb ) throws JSONException{
         System.out.println("starting pt");
         String output="Hello "+ nb.getName();
         nb.setName(output);
         return nb;
     }
}
```

Here is my NameBean class that is used to map JSON data:

```
public class NameBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

On the client side, I am using ajax to invoke this:

```
function Invoke(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/OnlineJudgeDemo/api/login/',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "name" : $("#haha").val()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert("wow!");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("sorry! " + textStatus+errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, when the invoke() function is called, it gives 415 Unsupported Media Type error.

I have checked many other Stack Overflow pages regarding the same problem, but none seems to solve my query.

Can somebody help me to know where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try rewriting your service as follows :

```
 @Path("/login")
 public class LoginWS {

   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public NameBean getHello( NameBean nb ) throws JSONException{
     System.out.println("starting pt");
     String output="Hello "+ nb.getName();
     nb.setName(output);
     return nb;
   }

 }
```